# meaning of differentiation of stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $X_t,t\in T $ continuous time stochastic process. What is the meaning of $dX_t$ which is differentiation of $X_t$?
Does that mean 
$X_{t+dt}$ and $X_t$ are random variables so $dX_t \approx X_{t+dt}-X_t$ is also random variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of stochastic differential equations, the meaning of $dX_t$ is "derived" from the definition of corresponding integrals $\mathcal I[f](\omega)=\int_S^Tf(t,\omega)dX_t(\omega)$. The integral is defined by suitable approximation of $f$ by elementary functions $\phi$ of the form $\phi(t,\omega)=\sum_j e_j(\omega)\cdot\chi_{[t_j,t_{j+1})}(t)$.

However, the problem is that the actually used suitable approximation strongly influences the definition of the resulting integral and its properties. The Ito integral corresponds more or less to using $e_j(\omega)=f(t_j,\omega)$, while using $e_j(\omega)=f(\frac{t_j+t_{j+1}}{2},\omega)$ leads to the Stratonovich integral.

If I try to translate these definitions back into your language/notation, the Ito integral would more or less correspond to your suggestion $dX_t \approx X_{t+dt}-X_t$, while the Stratonovich integral would correspond more or less to $dX_t \approx X_{t+dt/2}-X_{t-dt/2}$.

Comment: thank you for you answer,
in classic calculus $dX_t=X'dt$ represents the amount of the tangent line rises or falls when $t$ changes by amount $dt$. in stochastic calculus how can we interperet $dX_t$?

Comment: @cabri61 Because Brownian motion is (in a suitable sense) nowhere differentiable, thinking about tangent lines won't help. However, if you understand the [Stieltjes integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue–Stieltjes_integral) and the corresponding Stieltjes measure, then you might be able to appreciate an interpretation of $dX_t$ as a (stochastic) measure. (I say stochastic measure, because it's $dX_t(\omega)$, if we are careful about notation. I don't know whether $dX_t(\omega)$ is almost surely a Stieltjes measure for fixed $\omega$, but I guess not.)